# How to create a Bitmap and draw it in UWP?

Tags: c#, bitmap, uwp

I have a quite simple question today: how to create a bitmap and "draw" it, changing every single pixel in it, in a UWP app.

I have read many things here on StackOverflow, but now I am a little bit confused, because there are so many different types (WritableBitmap, SoftwareBitmap, BitmapImage, BitmapSource... now, in FCU, they added even BitmapIconSource...) and so many ways... but they mostly starts with a given image file or source, and it's not my case.

Let's say, e.g., that I want to create a 20x20 Bitmap and want to assign to every pixel a different argb value... and then assign it to a BitmapSource property.
What would be the best and efficient way, in a UWP?

Thank you for your patience and your attention.

Best regards

Comment: I suggest you look at the class-hierarchy diagrams for the various bitmap types you listed to see how they're related. For example, `WriteableBitmap` is a subclass of `BitmapSource`, and `BitmapSource` is not intended to be used directly by application developers.

Comment: I know it: I usually use a BitmapSource property in my AppViewModel to bind a bitmap to an Image XAML element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `WriteableBitmap` and modify it's `PixelBuffer` directly:

```
var wb = new WriteableBitmap(100, 100);                        
byte[] imageArray = new byte[100 * 100 * 4];
for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.Length; i += 4)
{
    //BGRA format
    imageArray[i] = 0; // Blue
    imageArray[i + 1] = 0;  // Green
    imageArray[i + 2] = 255; // Red
    imageArray[i + 3] = 255; // Alpha
}

using (Stream stream = wb.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
{
    //write to bitmap
    await stream.WriteAsync(imageArray, 0, imageArray.Length);
}

TargetImage.Source = wb;
```

If you want more abstraction, [look into `WriteableBitmapEx`](https://github.com/teichgraf/WriteableBitmapEx) which adds very useful and easy to use extension methods and helpers that make working with `WriteableBitmap` a breeze.